# What should I know before shopping for a SSL certificate?

Tags: https, security-certificate, forum

The users of a forum that I administer have requested that we switch to a https connection. I have never shopped for a SSL certificate before. I did a quick Google search and found a lot of different options, with huge differences in pricing.

Is there a crash course on this topic for someone's who's never done this before? Why is there such a big range on pricing?

Answer (score 0):

you should consider many factors

1. Price: Cost of SSL certificate
2. Application Range : Domain,subdomain or whole site

   3. Warranty: If they provide insurance against data forgery
   4. Acceptance : How many browser accept their certificate
   5. Encryption Strength : 128 Bit or 256 Bit , RSA 1 or RSA 2